# How to set a certain height for all table-colspans in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to set/define a certain height for all colspans in my tables automatically. The (empty) colspans just separate the table content visually in every second row (like the screenshot shows).

[image: Screenshot example of the table]

Their height has to be 20px. My very bad solution at this moment: to give each (!) colspan the same id which define the height from a CSS. But, I have to do this 1000 times via hand manually! I am sure there has to be an easier option to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you post the html? By the way, those are rows, not colspans. And if you need some empty space between each and every row, you can use `border-spacing`. Also, you should not give things the same ID.

Comment: id **must** be unique per document.

Comment: Just select those rows via attribute selectors in CSS: `[colspan="5"] { height: 20px; }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Ok, in CSS the code for the height is:
td#empty{
 height: 20px; 

And in html I have to code everytime this to load it:
<tr><td id="empty" colspan="5"></td></tr>

Comment: @PatrickDreid I suggested a solution using FlexBox, this don't <table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can target every other row in your table. Keep in mind that :nth-child doesn't work on older versions of IE.

Also don't use ID but classes.

```css
.mytable tr:nth-child(2n+2){
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="400" class="mytable">
 <tr>
  <td align="center">
   col1
  </td>
  <td align="center">
   col2
  </td>
  <td align="center">
   col3
  </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="3">
   colspan
  </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="center">
   col1
  </td>
  <td align="center">
   col2
  </td>
  <td align="center">
   col3
  </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="3">
   colspan
  </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="center">
   col1
  </td>
  <td align="center">
   col2
  </td>
  <td align="center">
   col3
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice too, thanks. You are using 2n+2, another user used "nth-child(4n+4)". Where is the difference?

Comment: @PatrickDreid the user that used 4n+4 is using <div> in his example. He has used 3 divs, plus a div for spacing so he want to target and set the height every 4 divs (start at four, then every other four div).
In my exmaple i have used rows (tr) so i am targeting every other row (every 2 rows). It depends if in your original code you are using tables or div, Hope it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes. Thank you. Moreover: Why no use of ID but classes?

Comment: And: your solution works, thx! The best solution of all for me as a coding newbie.

Comment: So why is this easier than `[colspan] { height: 20px; }` with the same table html? Regarding your question `why class not id` - do you even read the comments on your question? ***id must be unique per document.***

Comment: I like your way of subliminal rampage, honestly! :) As an obviously coding-noob and english-noob as well, I even dont understand this. Ok, id must be unique per document. But what does that mean for example? Which issues could result from this?

Answer (score 0):

As Mr Lister said you are best off using  `border-spacing` rather than trying to put what should be `rowspan` instead of `colspan`s. You can set your tables to have a top or bottom spacing that would spread them apart evenly, either do 10px for top and bottom or just 20px for one of them and it should give the same effect. That way you only have to set that in the css once and not '1000x manually'.

Comment: As I understand OP that is only **one** table, not many tables.

Comment: He says for all colspans in his tables

Comment: If each of those ones were a single table, why would he not just use `table { margin-bottom: 20px; }`?

Comment: `{ margin-bottom: 20px; }` is another solution yes, but he was using colspans so maybe he did not know. There are multiple solutions. Setting the colspan attribute in the CSS is also a good solution.

Comment: First: Thank you all for your help, really good ideas! Unfortunately I am a real noob at coding but I will try.

Moreover: I have more tables in the same way for different articles.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the table cells in those rows via [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in CSS:

```
[colspan] { height: 20px; }
```

Comment: Could you give me an short example with that? I am really no coding guy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean "short example"? This is all the code you need. Is it not short enough?

Comment: Oh, sry for my english. SOmetimes I translate directly my mother language into yours and so this happened ^^

I meant: Could you give me  an working example with including this code in a html table?

Comment: Why would I? You have the HTML already. Just add this to your CSS.

Comment: Since you seem to be too lazy to read about attribute selectors: `[colspan]` selects all elements (regardless of element *type*) that have a `colspan` attribute.

Comment: I am more "too stupid" than "too lazy" for doing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try FlexBox

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.table .col {
  width: 33%;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table .col:nth-child(4n+4) {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

Live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/5z6v28L7/

Comment: Never heard flexbox. Sounds interesting. But why the few pixels more at the end of all colspan-rows? See the screenshot: [link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170128/qk3a9rwz.jpg)

Comment: .table .col {width: 33% replase an width: 33.333% https://jsfiddle.net/5z6v28L7/1/

Comment: Is the width important in your code? I am using exactly px for the width which is sometimes a little bit different.

And: Does your code work with few or more columns too?

Comment: Yes, width is important, if  use more columns you need change value :
width: 33%; and (4n+4)

Comment: Honestly as a Coding-Newbie I am not understanding why the width is important for a certain height? In my tables the width is in px and sometimes different. Would be great to have a solution without a certain width, because otherwise I fear I will destroy the code..